# Datastax spark filter data very slow

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am using DSE Analytics to analyse data, 4 EC2 server m5ad.xlarge(4 cores & 16GB RAM, 3 analytics and 1 Cassandra)

2 dc like this:

[image]

In Cassandra the keyspace size is around 9GB, total 20mil rows(50 columns) 
And the query:

```
        t0 = time() 
        df = exclusive_df.groupBy('id_store','id_area').agg(
            F.sum("numberin").alias("total_people")            
            ).orderBy("id_store")
        df.show()            
        tt = str(time() - t0)
```

It took almost 10min to execute query, the CPU, memory like above(not use all resources). And the stages is:

[image]

I don't know what caused slow query in this case, maybe because I missed some configuration for workers, or lack of servers/partitions?

Answer (score 1):

Your Spark job is running on only one node, which is the driver. Meaning no executors are involved in the job. Therefore the whole job is executed one task after the other and not in parallel.

"maybe because I missed some configuration for workers, or lack of servers"? - Excatly. This is the case.

You either haven't registered the servers to Spark driver or your configuration is wrong.

Check your config values in spark-env.sh. See if there is a limit on spark.cores.max.

Also make sure you have actually provided Spark with the executors' IPs.

More information: [DataStax - Configuring Spark nodes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkConfiguration.html#sparkConfiguration__sparkCfgMem)